# How to count the elemets of the XML column with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm really new about the SQL Server,

I'd like to count the elements from a XML's column.

Here a brifly explain about my issue. 
As first time I created a temporany table because I need to use another column from an other table to filter my elements in the XLM colums. Upto here I didn't have a problem.
To do this I wrote this query:

```
SELECT  a.columnINT AS AC, b.columnXML AS BC
INTO #table1
FROM dbo.a left join dbo.b
ON dbo.b.id = dbo.a.id
```

After this I created a temporary table with two columns. One a integer column and the second one with a column that has per every row an XML code.

Here a part of the XML code

```
<x>
  <x1>
    <x2>1.10.100.1000</x2>
  </x1>
</x>
```

I tried to write this query to count `x2` for 20 million of rows, but doesn't work.

```
SELECT COUNT(BC.query('/x1/x2').value('.', 'varchar(20)')) AS XML
FROM #table1
where AC = 10
```

Is it possible to count within an XML element or is it a wrong conceptually?

Somebody, please, could tell me where I wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Francesco

Comment: Note sure I follow, are you trying to count the number of times the node `/x1/x2/` appears? In your data that would be `0`, as those values have a root of `x` (so `/x/x1/x2`).

Comment: @Larnu Hi and thank you for your answer. Yes, I try to count the node x2 appears. I'm going to try your suggestion. 

About the concept, what I did is correct?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading through the lines correctly, are you after this?

```
SELECT COUNT(X.X2.value('(./text())[1])', 'varchar(15)')) AS X2
FROM #table1 T1
     CROSS APPLY T1.BC.nodes('/x/x1/x2') X(X2)
WHERE AC = 10;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodes method to count XML nodes.
In the example to modified the path to have some matches.

```
CREATE TABLE #T (A int, BC xml)
INSERT INTO #T VALUES 
(1,'<x>
  <x1>
    <x2>1.10.100.1000</x2>
    <x2>xxxx</x2>
  </x1>
</x>');


SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM #T AS T
CROSS APPLY T.BC.nodes('/x/x1/x2') AS N(X)
WHERE A=1

DROP TABLE #T
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 100 object_id AS AC, CAST(REPLICATE(CAST('<x><x1><x2>1.10.100.1000</x2></x1></x>' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), object_id%1000) AS XML) AS BC
INTO #table1
FROM sys.objects;


SELECT *, BC.value('count(/x/x1/x2)', 'int') AS x2counter
FROM #table1 T1;


DROP TABLE #table1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. :)